# Reading 1256ara encoding (Arabic letters) from sybase using php-apache2

Tags: php, encoding, sybase

I'm facing a problem reading arabic letters from a sybase database on php-apache2. I'm using an ODBC connector, and the select query returns only english letters.

My problem is I can't modify the database encoding.
I tried using `iconv()`, and setting charset in the header with no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it! 
In my select query i cast the column containing Arabic characters as `varbinary`, then i used `iconv('windows-1256','utf-8,$stringToDisplay)`

Answer (score 0):

If the database has 1256 encoding, then set the client charset accordingly when making the connection to the database (there should be a way of specifying the charset at that point). Note that Sybase ASE supports the 'cp1256' charset but not '1256ara'.